# Can I ignore the execution of arguments on mocked functions in jest?

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

I am mocking a couple of function calls in express using jest:

```
jest.mock('express', () => {
    return () => {
        return {
            disable: jest.fn(),
            use: jest.fn(),
            set: jest.fn(),
            get: jest.fn(),
            post: jest.fn(),
        }
    }
});
```

In my app.js the mocked functions are then invoked:

```
create: () => {
    const app = express()
    app.use(someFunction())
    app.disable(anotherFunction())
    app.set(yetAnotherFunction())
}
```

Is there a way that the arguments i.e `someFunction`, `anotherFunction`.. are not evaluated? I want them to be completely ignored. Although not entirely sure if it's possible...

Comment: you can stub them, so they'll call stub instead. How do you import them into your app?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way around it without creating more stubs (if there isn't that's what I will do)... they are functions that live alongside the module I am testing... the calls fail because I stubbed some of its dependencies...

Comment: stubbing is fine solution :)